# Ajax call error after opening infowindow

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using gmap3 for google map on my site.

I locate a marker after click on a button. Everyclick will give me different location depend on what a user chooses.

It goes smooth, however, when the user click on the marker to open the info window, and close it, the ajax call doesn't work. It gives me this error on chrome console, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'lat' of undefined" in main.js.

EDIT: it seems I forgot to put autofit{} from my code, and it seems this was the problem. Anyone know how to user autofit in this case?

Here is my code

```
 // create a map
$('#map_canvas').gmap3({
  map: {
    options: {
      center: [-2.899153, 117.722626],
      zoom: 4,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    }
  }
});
$('.locate-btn').on('click', function() {
var place_id = $('.place').val();
var address = $('.address').val();
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax.php',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: 'place_id=' + place_id + '&address=' + address,
  beforeSend: function() {
    $('.loading').append("<img src='/images/loading.gif'  id='loader' />");
  },
  success: function(place) {
    $('#map_canvas').gmap3({
      marker: {
        latLng: [place.lat, place.lng],
        data: '<a href="#" class="btn btn-info">nearest hotels</a><a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">about</a>',
        events: {
          click: function(marker, event, context) {
            var map = $(this).gmap3('get'),
              infowindow = $(this).gmap3({
                get: {
                  name: 'infowindow'
                }
              });
            if (infowindow) {
              infowindow.close();
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
              infowindow.setContent(context.data);
            } else {
              $(this).gmap3({
                infowindow: {
                  anchor: marker,
                  options: {
                    content: context.data
                  }
                }
              });
            }
          }
        }
      },
      autofit: {}
    });
  }
});
});
});
```

Would anyone tell what's wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: The error shows that the place that you are getting in success is not set. maybe it is getting no data.

Comment: you are using place.lat and when place is not defined maybe getting no data then this error comes because place is not defined its .lat cannot be called.

Comment: do you have a live example of what you are trying ?